# How to solve the exception "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher."

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter mobile application.  When I do flutter run, I get the following error.  I am not so familiar with Android.  I know that I am not using "sign_in_with_apple" my self.

Things that I tried but did not help:

```
flutter clean
rm pubspec.lock
flutter pub upgrade  
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Could someone help.
Thanks

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':sign_in_with_apple' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
```

Here is how the android/build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is how my pubspec.yaml file looks like:

```
name: ###
description: ###
version: 1.1.1+18
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
  flutter: 3.3.8

dependencies:
  android_id: ^0.1.3+1
  badges: ^2.0.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.6
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+6
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.5
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.8
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.7
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.7
  flash: ^2.0.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.5+1
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3+20
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  http: ^0.13.5
  image_cropper: ^3.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  linkable: ^3.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7096
  open_mail_app: ^0.4.5
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  pattern_formatter: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  purchases_flutter: ^4.5.0
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.3
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  timeago: ^3.3.0
  tuple: ^2.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^0.3.0
  very_good_analysis: ^3.1.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/env/
    - assets/email_icons/
    - assets/flags/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/json/
    - assets/social_icons/
```

UPDATE:
I replace the deprecated flutterfire_ui with firebase_ui_firestore as suggested by @Yashraj.  After running "flutter clean" and "flutter run", I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I noticed that the only way I can run successful "flutter run" is if I delete android/app/build but when I try to run the command again for another android device.  The build fails.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file as well?

Comment: Which build gradle do you want me to post?  the one under app/ or above app? I included android/build.gradle in the post. Thanks

Comment: Can you add your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: I added pubspec.yaml in the post

Comment: I noticed that the only way I can make 1 build is if I delete android/app/build.  But I can't make two build for two devices at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error because `flutterfire_ui`: ^0.4.3+20 package is depends on `sign_in_with_apple`.

`flutterfire_ui` is deprecated.

You need to follow some steps to configure `flutterfire_ui`.

Read Readme file : https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of flutterfire_ui  since it is deprecated and I started using firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.1.1.  I ran "flutter clean", then I "flutter run".  Now I am getting this error: ```FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1```

Comment: Remove pubspec.lock file and after that do flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Still getting issue then try with flutter pub cache repair command.

Comment: I just did but got he same error.  The only way I can make a successfull build is if I delete android/app/build.  When I do that, I can make single build for single device.  Trying to build for another device will get me same error.

Comment: Maybe it's other issues but I hope you got rid of kotlin version issue.

Comment: Yes, I got rid of kotlin version issue. Thanks for your help on that

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing the version of Kotlin as shown and try:

```
dependencies{
  classpath "org.jetbrains,kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
}
```

Comment: I noticed that the only way I can make 1 build is if I delete android/app/build. But I can't make two build for two devices at the same time. When I run "flutter run" again for the second device, I get this error: ```FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.```